# Rails FTP downloading images: too many files open

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, ftp, ruby-on-rails-3.2, paperclip

I know the "Too many files open" error occurs when files are opened without closing them, but despite doing that (I think) I'm still getting this error:

```
remote_photos_list do |remote_path|
  Net::FTP.open(ip, username, password) do |ftp|
    tmp_path = File.join('tmp/images', File.basename(remote_path))
    ftp.getbinaryfile(remote_path, tmp_path)
    File.open(tmp_path, 'r') do |file|
      listing.photos.create(:image => file)
    end
    File.delete(tmp_path)
  end
end
```

The error occurs at the `listing.photos.create(:image => file)` line on the first iteration.

I've tried nesting the outermost blocks in opposite orders, downloading via HTTP instead, and restarting my machine (this is occurring locally), but all to no avail. From what I've seen on StackExchange and Google, this seems like it should be a very simple problem, but I just can't get rid of this error.

This is occurring on a local Rails 3.2.13 server on a Mac OS X, and `listing` is an instance of a `Listing` model that `has_many :photos`, where `Photo` has a Paperclip attachment called `image`, if any of that is helpful.

I also don't know if the `tmp_file` generation is necessary; if there's a way around that, please let me know, since maybe it would help.

Again, I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I would very much appreciate any help!

Comment: Maybe you could try to open the file once before the loop and use it for each iteration (by emptying it each time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesting each file open within a `begin…rescue` block did the trick:

```
remote_photos_list do |remote_path|
  tmp_path = File.join('tmp/images', File.basename(remote_path))
  begin
    Net::FTP.open(ip, username, password) do |ftp|
      ftp.getbinaryfile(remote_path, tmp_path)
      File.open(tmp_path, 'r') do |file|
        listing.photos.create(:image => file)
      end
    end
    Rails.logger.info "File #{remote_path} download succeeded"
  rescue
    Rails.logger.info "File #{remote_path} download FAILED"
    #***try something else***
  ensure
    File.delete(tmp_path) if File.exist?(tmp_path)
  end
end
```

I'm not sure if this is because certain files are too large or something else, but I suppose `begin…rescue` blocks will almost always be necessary for dealing with remote files.